# Python KeyError from trying to format from dictonary key

Tags: python, json, dictionary, formatting

I'm trying to let you use values from other keys in a configuration dictionary, but it doesn't work, (sorry if it's a stupid question im new to python coming from c++). I am converting it to a json object since it returns a string and you can only format strings

The code:

```py
import getopt, sys, json

def main():
    dicto = {"key":"yes", "cool":"{key}"}
    str_dicto = json.dumps(dicto)
    print(dicto)
    print(str_dicto.format(key = dicto["key"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName>python test.py

C:\Users\MyUserName>python test.py
{'key': 'yes', 'cool': '{key}'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\test.py", line 7, in main
    print(str_dicto.format(key = dicto["key"]))
KeyError: '"key"'
```

Comment: It happens because json format confuse python formatting parser. Better to avoid using string formatting with json string, you can work with dict before dumping it to string,

Comment: @OlvinRoght But how do i format it without dumping it to JSON?

Comment: `dicto["cool"] = dicto["key"]` or if you want universal solution which will replace any `{key}` *(where `key` could be any of dictionary keys)* you can use next dict comp: `dicto = {k: dicto[v[1:-1]] if isinstance(v, str) and v.startswith("{") and v.endswith("}") and v[1:-1] in dicto else v for k, v in dicto.items()}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use string.Template:

```
from string import Template

def main():
    dicto = {"key":"yes", "cool":'$key'}
    t = Template(str(dicto))
    str_dicto = t.substitute(key=dicto['key'])
    print(str_dicto)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```
{'key': 'yes', 'cool': 'yes'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that there is an extra pair of brackets

You would have better luck doing this:

```py
import getopt, sys, json

def main():
    dicto = {"key":"yes", "cool": '{key}'}
    str_dicto = json.dumps(dicto)
    print(dicto)
    print(str_dicto.replace('{key}', dicto["key"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```py
{'key': 'yes', 'cool': '{key}'}
{"key": "yes", "cool": "yes"}
```

Which would achieve the same thing as converting the dict to a str instead of json dumping it

```py
import getopt, sys, json

def main():
    dicto = {"key":"yes", "cool": '{key}'}
    str_dicto = str(dicto)
    print(dicto)
    print(str_dicto.replace('{key}', dicto["key"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```py
{'key': 'yes', 'cool': '{key}'}
{'key': 'yes', 'cool': 'yes'}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It's not the best, because it would create problems with json string encoding. E.g. if value of `dicto["key"]` will be `'"abs'`. And your first option with double quotes was better.

Comment: Convert it straight to a string ¯\_(ツ)_/¯... oh ok

Comment: Just use next: `print(str_dicto.replace('"{key}"', json.dumps(dicto["key"])))`

Comment: That doesn't work, the reason why it's raising a key error, is because it is trying to format the entire string (because it is wrapped in curly brackets because it was a dict)

Comment: If you are going to treat it like a string there are two simple solutions: `str_dicto[1:-1].format(key = dicto["key"])`, removing the curly brackets (but then you would have to add them back later) or format the `{key}`s manually, `str_dicto.replace('{key}', dicto["key"])`